# How to find the average runtime of this program

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

def search(lst, x):

for item in lst:

$\space \space\space\space $   if item == x:

$\space \space\space\space $$\space \space\space\space $return True

$\space \space\space$ return False

if the allowed input is a random list of length **n** made up of random elements from {1,2....10} which can be repeated

How do I prove that the average runtime is $\theta$(1)

I've tried so many ways but i keep on getting $\theta$(n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume your list is not sorted, but each element is a random selection from $1$ to $10$.  The problem does not say that, but it seems the appropriate assumption.  Punch the problem setter in the nose for me.  You are looking for whether there is at least one $x$ in the list.  For large $n$ you find one with probability approaching $1$.  The chance of stopping at $i$ loops is $\frac {9^{i-1}}{10^i}$ because you need $i-1$ values that are not $x$ followed by $x$.  The expected run time is $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac {i9^{i-1}}{10^i}+\frac {9^n}{10^n}$.  The first term converges to a constant, so is $O(1)$.  The second term goes to zero, so the sum is $O(1)$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. will this also be true if i replace {1,2...10} with {1,2...500}

Comment: You should think about it.  Does the same argument go through, just changing the constants?

Answer (score 0):

If the list is *literally* $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$, then the algorithm is *guaranteed* to finish in $10$ steps. That's **constant** time.

If the list is of variable length $n$, but the list is sorted in ascending order starting from $1$, then you know that the algorithm will return `True` if $x\leq n$, and `False` otherwise. That's one comparison, and so it's **constant** time.

If the list is of variable length $n$, but the list is sorted in ascending order starting from $a$, then you know that the algorithm will return `True` if $a \leq x\leq n$, and `False` otherwise. That's two comparisons, and so it's **constant** time.

But if the list is of variable length $n$ and sorting is not guaranteed, then you *must* check every item to know for sure whether $x$ is in the list. That requires checking $n$ elements and so it's **linear** time.

Comment: We are asked for average running time, not maximum.

Comment: @RossMillikan The maximum is $\Theta(n)$, the minimum is $O(1)$, and the average is $O(\frac n2) \sim O(n)$, no?

Comment: @RossMillikan And, of course, the average running time of an alto whose maximum time is constant is $\Theta(1)$

Comment: You are correct about the max and min, but the average is constant for large $n$ because you (almost) always stop fairly soon.